# How to use monit too with Rails default webrick server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu-12.04, monit

I am looking out to use monit tool for my Rails app.As this is my first attempting in using any monitoring tool can anybody guide me or point me to some references on how can I set up and use **monit** tool with the default Rails Webrick server (local development environment) ? I found the following references but all of them showcases monit config for a Apache, Nginx etc.

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-configure-monit
- http://blog.noizeramp.com/2011/09/16/monit-configuration-for-rails-stack/
- http://channaly.wordpress.com/2011/12/26/using-monit-to-monitor-delayed_job-in-rails-3/

Environment:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-09-23 revision 33323) [i686-linux]
- Rails 3.2.6
- Monit version 5.3.2

Thanks,

Jignesh